# AngularJS Load more function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, api, loading

So I am trying to make load more function.I am fetching data from twitch API and it comes as array of objects.

```
 $scope.loadData = function () {

 $http.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=9&offset=" + $scope.x).then(function(response) {
    $scope.myName = response.data.streams;
    $scope.link="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=";
     return $scope.x=$scope.x + 9; });  }; 
    //initial load
    $scope.loadData();
```

$scope.myName is array in which data is stored and it is used in ng-repeat.
$scope.x is variable used for offset and after clicking button it is incremented and is used to fetch new streams.So when I click button it removes old 9 streams and loads new 9 streams.I want to keep my old 9 streams and to just add 9 more everytime button is clicked.
See here: https://plnkr.co/edit/TbOf9hkPILJn2snW8D7A  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you loading 3 different angular versions? Especially why load angular-2 when your code is set for angular-1?

Comment: That is just for plnkr cause sometimes it doesn't work so I load all just be sure.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense and just over complicates demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood problem well, you should just append your data array instead of replacing it:

```
$scope.myName = [];
$scope.loadData = function () {

 $http.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit=9&offset=" + $scope.x).then(function(response) {
    // add streams to existing array
    Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.myName, response.data.streams);

    $scope.link="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=";
     return $scope.x=$scope.x + 9; });  }; 
    //initial load
    $scope.loadData();
```

Comment: simpler to use something like `Array.push.apply()`

Comment: Yeeees that is it,thank you both very much :) I knew that I needed to append,just couldn't find right syntax. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

[HERE IS THE SOLUTION OF PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/FcjihMgeIHCqOjF3AfVH?p=preview)

I've modified Streamovi controller and added load more button at the bottom so you can trigger loading more

```
app.controller('Streamovi', function($scope, $http) {

  var ITEMS_PER_LOAD = 9;
  var offset = 0;
  $scope.myName = [];

  function loadStreams(){
    $http.get("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?limit="+ITEMS_PER_LOAD+'&offset='+offset).then(function(response) {
      $scope.myName = $scope.myName.concat(response.data.streams);
      $scope.link="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=";
      offset+=ITEMS_PER_LOAD;
    });
  }

  //handler for the "Load More" button in the view.
  $scope.loadMore = function(){
    loadStreams();
  }

  //initial Loading
    loadStreams();
});
```

Comment: Thank you :) Works like a charm.